# Smack messaging client other than Chat Text

Tags: java, xmpp, smack

client1 can send txt message to client2 using

```
connection.getChatManager().createChat(to, this).sendMessage(message);
```

How to send other kind of message: like INFO message ? (client1 to client2) ?

Because I want, INFO message should not be displayed in the chat window....is it possible ? using smack, smackx library.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want do do here is to add an extension to your text message. Here is a rough guide.

```
Chat chat = connection.getChatManager().createChat(to, this);
Message message = new Message(to, Message.Type.chat);
message.setBody("hello");
message.setProperty(prop0, val0);
message.setProperty(prop1, val1);
chat.sendMessage(message)
```

The properties are carried in a separate namespace (use `toXML()` to look at it) and will not appear in the chat window. On the 'other side', the applications uses `getProperty()` to retrieve the value.

If you do not want key/value pairs, but structured data, use `addExtension()` in the message body. This is a little more complicated because you basically have to extend `PacketExtension`, provide your own namespace. You might even have to write a `PacketExtensionProvider`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example for message extension.
The basic XML structure of the XMPP protocol is：

```
<message  
    from='sender_jid'  
    to='receiver_jid'  
    type='message_type'>  
  <body> content </body>  
</message>
```

The process of sending messages：

```
//build chat  
Chat chat = chatManager.createChat("jid");  

//build extension  
UserInfo4XMPP userInfo4XMPP = new UserInfo4XMPP();  
userInfo4XMPP.setNameText("userx");  
userInfo4XMPP.setUrlText("http://www.liaoku.org/");  

//build message  
Message message = new Message();  
message.setBody("hello");  
message.addExtension(userInfo4XMPP);// add the extension  

//send  
chat.sendMessage(message);
```

The UserInfo4XMPP is defined as：

```
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.ExtensionElement;  

public class UserInfo4XMPP implements ExtensionElement{  

    private String elementName = "userinfo";   
    private String nameElement = "name";  
    private String urlElement = "url";  
    private String nameText = "";  
    private String urlText = "";  

    @Override  
    public String getElementName() {  
        return elementName;  
    }  

    @Override  
    public CharSequence toXML() {  
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();  

        sb.append("<");  
        sb.append(elementName);  
        sb.append(">");  

            sb.append("<");  
            sb.append(nameElement);  
            sb.append(">");  
            sb.append(nameText);  
            sb.append("</");  
            sb.append(nameElement);  
            sb.append(">");  

            sb.append("<");  
            sb.append(urlElement);  
            sb.append(">");  
            sb.append(urlText);  
            sb.append("</");  
            sb.append(urlElement);  
            sb.append(">");  

        sb.append("</");  
        sb.append(elementName);  
        sb.append(">");  

        return sb.toString();  
    }  

    @Override  
    public String getNamespace() {  
        return "";  
    }  

    public String getNameText() {  
        return nameText;  
    }  

    public void setNameText(String nameText) {  
        this.nameText = nameText;  
    }  

    public String getUrlText() {  
        return urlText;  
    }  

    public void setUrlText(String urlText) {  
        this.urlText = urlText;  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A more complicated example of message extention:

```
Message videoMsg = new Message();
VideoChatRTP videoXml = new VideoChatRTP();
videoXml.setVideoType(VideoMediaType.REQUEST);
videoXml.setAddress(address);
videoMsg.setTo(receive);
videoMsg.addExtension(videoXml);
XMPPConnection conn = BaseService.getInstance().getConnection();
conn.sendPacket(videoMsg);
```

The extension class VideoChatRIP must implement PacketExtension:

```
public class VideoChatRTP implements PacketExtension {
    private VideoMediaType videoType;
    private String address;
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
    public VideoMediaType getVideoType() {
        return videoType;
    }
    public void setVideoType(VideoMediaType videoType) {
        this.videoType = videoType;
    }
    public static final String NAME = "jingle";
    public static final String NAME_SPACE = "com:roger:video";
    public VideoChatRTP() {
        super();
    }
    @Override
    public String getElementName() {
        return NAME;
    }
    @Override
    public String getNamespace() {
        return NAME_SPACE;
    }
    @Override
    public String toXML() {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        sb.append("<jingle").append(" xmlns=\"").append(NAME_SPACE).append(
                "\">");
        sb.append("<type>").append(videoType).append("</type>");
        sb.append("<ipAddress>").append(address).append("</ipAddress>");
        sb.append("</jingle>");
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

The Listener:

```
ProviderManager.getInstance().addExtensionProvider(VideoChatRTP.NAME, VideoChatRTP.NAME_SPACE, new VideoChatReceive());
```

Processing:

```
public class VideoChatReceive implements PacketExtensionProvider {
    @Override
    public PacketExtension parseExtension(XmlPullParser parser)
            throws Exception {
        boolean done = false;
        String requestType = "asdasd";
        String ipAddress = "asdasd";
        while (!done) {
            int eventType = parser.next();
            String name = parser.getName();
            if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                if (name.equals("type")) {
                    requestType = parser.nextText();
                }
                if (name.equals("ipAddress")) {
                    ipAddress = parser.nextText();
                }
            }
            if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                if (name.equals("jingle")) {
                    done = true;
                }
            }
        }
        VideoChatRTP videoRtp = new VideoChatRTP();
        videoRtp.setVideoType(VideoMediaType.valueOf(requestType));

        videoRtp.setAddress(ipAddress);
        return videoRtp;
    }
}
```